# What is the real part of $(i+1)^{20}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

Do I have to calculate it all out? That would be a pretty long calculation and boring... Is there an easier ways to find the real part? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(i+1)^{ 20 }={ \left( { \left( i+1 \right)  }^{ 2 } \right)  }^{ 10 }={ \left( 2i \right)  }^{ 10 }={ 2 }^{ 10 }{ i }^{ 2\cdot 4+2 }=-{ 2 }^{ 10 }$$

Comment: (+1) Hard to be faster :D

Comment: I like this answer better than the DeMoivre approach since it's a bit cleaner. I wouldn't have thought to do it this way, but it's pretty elegant.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I didn't think about the fact to decompose ^20 into ^2^10!! You're a genious

Comment: @CameronWilliams I like this answer less than the De Moivre approach, which is much more general.

Comment: @egreg Yeah in general I like DeMoivre a lot more, but for this example, this approach was pretty nice.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Try the same for $(\sqrt{3}+i)^{20}$.

Comment: @egreg Yes.....? I mean I just agreed with you...

Answer (score 3):

$1+i=\sqrt 2e^{i\pi/4}$, this implies that $(1+i)^{20}=2^{10}e^{5\pi}=-2^{10}$.

Comment: If I don't ask to much, could you please explain me why 1+i = sqrt(2)e^(i*PI/2)?(Can you use LaTeX in comments?)

Comment: It's [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity).  And yes you can use MathJax in comments.

Comment: $cos(\pi/4)=sin(\pi/4)={{\sqrt 2}\over 2}$, and $e^{i\pi/4}=cos(\pi/4)+isin(\pi/4)$.

Comment: @DanielCortild $|1+i|=\sqrt{2}$ by direct computation, so $1+i=\sqrt{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i)=\sqrt{2}(\cos\frac{\pi}{4}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{4})$

Answer (score 0):

You could write the complex number in the form $|r|(\cos(\phi)+i\sin(\phi))$ where r is the modulus of the complex number and phi is the argument, and then use DE Moivre's formula to solve the power $(|r|(\cos(\phi)+i\sin(\phi)))^n=|r|^n((\cos(n\phi)+i\sin(n\phi)))$